# jQuery append strange behavior on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

When I try to add element to the div by clicking the button IE8 don't add it until I press it the second time. Then it adds two new elements. Here is the code:

```
$(options.addButton).click(function(event) {
    var prototype = $(options.prototypeContainer).attr('data-prototype');
    event.preventDefault();
    var fileField = $(prototype.replace(/__name__/g, fieldCount));
    fieldCount++;
    $(options.uploadingImagesWrapper).append(fileField);
    //fileField.slideDown();
    return false;
});
```

The markup of the container goes like this:

```
<div id="uploading-component-images">
    <!-- here I inserts new elements -->
</div>

<!-- the button the triggers insertion function -->
<a class="btn" href="#" id="add-another-image">{{'label.component.add_image_field'|trans }}</a>
```

And the single element markup looks like this:

```
<div class="image-file-field">
    <input type="file" name="{{ full_name }}[file]" id="{{ id }}" />
    <button type="button" class="offset0_5 remove-image btn btn-mini">
       <span class="icon-remove"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot - maybe with it it will be more easy to understand. http://joxi.ru/RFBeUtg5CbBaNyCgm14
The version of jquery is 1.9.1

Comment: Please specify the jQuery version you're using.

Comment: What does the markup this is dealing with look like? Kind of important to the question...

Comment: Could you explain why do you use `event.preventDefault();` and `return false;` here?

Comment: About event.preventDefault() and "return false;" - I was just playing around with this problem and added return false just in case.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the exact same issue. I'm was originally thinking it was a tag that isn't closed properly but that wouldn't explain why it shows up after a second append. Kinda at a loss

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Try these steps (in no particular order):

1. put in `event.stopPropagation()` after `event.preventDefault()`
2. use html() instead (or try other variations, like `insertAfter())`
3. use `$('body').append(...)` and then use element.offset to position it in with the correct height and left. This last one worked for me. It's a pain but then so is IE8.

Here's my code (I'm using an event object to get offset, you can get the same behaviour using jQuery's `offset()):`

```
var overflow = $('#overflowContainer');
var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // if window scrolled then need to minus    this from the height so that menu stays in correct place
var target = $($event.currentTarget);
var offset = target.offset();
var dd_top = ((offset.top + target.outerHeight()) - windowScrollTop);
$('body').append(overflow); // must append it to the body for IE to work                        
var left = target.offset().left;
overflow.css({                            
   "top": dd_top + "px",
    "position": "fixed", 
    "left": left // right-aligned with right border of overflow container
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `event.preventDefault();` or move it below the append sentense.